# How to link a project to GCP credits linked to a different account?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I need a guide on linking a project to an account with gcp credits. We are a startup and have received gcp credits for testing, but the credits are linked to the personal account of previous admin who is no longer working for us but has allowed us to continue using the project and credits until it expires. That is the only option available from GCP, the credits cant be transferred. So I want to create more projects and want to use the credits linked to the previous admin. The previous admin has agreed to link the project. I want to know the exact steps to link the resource usage of the new project to the credits.

I have gone through https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/modify-project
however when I hit change billing it says there's no other billing account available as I have only a single billing account.

Comment: Do you have a GCP organization? The credits are assigned to a billing account. Use that billing account to pay for projects. You an change the business name, etc for a billing account so that you do not need permission from the previous admin. Assing yourself as the Primary contact and remove the old admin. https://console.cloud.google.com/billing

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to ask to the previous Admin, which is the billing owner to do a few steps for you.
This is needed because he is the Billing Owner of the account.
Taking a look at the link you sent, you can find this information about permissions need to add the project and so on.

If you check there, these are the permissions needed in order to enable the billing for a project [1]:
 - Project Owner or Project Billing Manager on the project, AND Billing Account Administrator or Billing Account User for the target Cloud Billing account.

I guess that you are Proj Owner of your project, but you aren't a Billing Account User of this Free Trial account with the credits.
If you want to take an advise, you could ask the previous admin to set your project under his billing account.
Or he will need to grant the permissions for you.

Either way, you need him to set up this for you, as he has the account being billed.

And an important reminder, you can't change the ownership of the trial account to another email address.

[1] - https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/modify-project#enable_billing_for_a_new_project